# non-admins can not delete images in tx_news in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, tx-news, typo3-12.x

I have a small problem and it's that a TYPO3 user who is not an admin can no longer delete images and media from a news. Is this a known problem or are there still configuration possibilities somewhere? The problem occurred after I updated from TYPO3 v10 to TYPO3 v12 and news v11.2. I have a similar website, with the same configuration, the same user group and there it works strangely.

logged in as admin:
[image: logged in as admin]

logged in as editor:
[image: logged in as editor]

The problem occurs only with the news. The editor can delete normal images as usual.

I have installed an older news version without success. I have given the user group "editors" all possible permissions that are selectable, however the user cannot delete the images from the news until he is created as admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the permissions to modify (`tx_news_domain_model_news`) records you must grant the permission for editing the field (`fal_media`?).

In general you also can restrict/grant permissions on page level with the **Access**-module and the permissions given for this page depending on `Owner`, `Group`, `Everybody` of that page.

Comment: Damn, actually I had to give the group permission to edit and delete in the access-module for the news folder. Since then it has never been a problem like that.... Thanks for the tip!